# When do tags get deleted?

Tags: support

According to this [Meta Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags), 'zombie' tags are meant to be deleted at 03:00 UTC every day.

How do we have over a page and a half of tags that are not removed yet? Are they tag synonyms?

Comment: Yes, yes they are.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン can we remove the [physical] tag then?